# Is the mentioned basis a Gröbner basis?

Tags: commutative-algebra, ideals, groebner-basis

It's mentioned into my notes that if the ideal given as  $I=\langle x+y+z, 3x-2y\rangle$, then $\{x+y+z, 5y+3z\}$ is a Gröbner basis for the ideal. I can see how $I=\langle x+y+z, 3x-2y\rangle=\langle x+y+z, 5y+3z\rangle$. The initial of the ideal with respect to the lexicographic ordering $x>y>z$, denoted as, $in_<(I)=\langle in_<(x+y+z),in_<(3x-2y)\rangle=\langle x,3x\rangle=\langle x\rangle$. By the notes definition of a Gröbner basis, $in_<(I) =\langle in_<(x+y+z), in_<(5y+3z)\rangle=\langle x,5y\rangle$, but clearly $\langle x\rangle\neq\langle x,5y\rangle$. Is the example in my notes wrong, or am I getting the definition of a Gröbner basis wrong. If it is wrong, can someone please provide a correct basis.

Comment: I'll update it with the correct definition

Comment: The condition should be $\text{in}(I)=(\text{in}(g_1),...,\text{in}(g_n))$, where $g_i$ is the Groebner basis. And that is the correct basis.

Comment: so in this example $<x>=<x,5y>$?

Comment: No. You need to remember that $\text{in}(I)$ is equal to the ideal generated by the initial monomials of **all** elements of $I$, not just of the generators given. You are probably saying that $\text{in}(I)=(x)$ bacause you are computing only the initial monomials of the generators $h_1:=x+y+z$ and $h_2:=3x-2y$. But $3h_1-h_2\in I$ and $\text{in}(3h_1-h_2)=y$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $I=(f_1,\dots,f_m)$, then we don't necessarily have $\operatorname{in}_{<}(I)=(\operatorname{in}_{<}(f_1),\dots,\operatorname{in}_{<}(f_m))$. (Recall that by definition $\operatorname{in}_{<}(I)$ is generated by $\operatorname{in}_{<}(f)$ for *all* $f\in I$.) The equality holds if and only if $f_1,\dots,f_m$ is a Gröbner basis of $I$.