# Showing that for every monomial $x^u\in\operatorname{in}_{<}(I)$, there exists $f\in I$ s.t. $\operatorname{in}_<(f)=x^u$

Tags: commutative-algebra, ideals, monomial-ideals

> Given an ideal $I\subset R=K[x_1, ...,x_n]$ and let $<$ be a term order on the ring $R$. I must show that $\forall x^u\in\operatorname{in}_<(I)$, $\exists f\in I$ s.t. $\operatorname{in}_<(f)=x^u$, where $u\in\mathbb{N}^n$ and $x^u=x^{(u_1,...,u_n)}:=x_1^{u_1}\cdots x_n^{u_n}$.

At first sight it looks like this follows directly from the definition of $\operatorname{in}_<(I):=\{\operatorname{in}_<(f):f\in I\}$, since $\forall x^u\in in_<(I),\space x^u = \operatorname{in}_<(f)$ for some $f\in I$.

However, I'm then given the hint to use the fact that $\operatorname{in}_<(fg)=\operatorname{in}_<(f)\operatorname{in}_<(g)$.

I'm unsure about what this question is asking, I've read the question countless times and it still seems to me like it's directly from the definition, but then how would the hint be useful?

Comment: Note that you have the definition of $in_<(I)$ wrong. It is the *ideal generated by* all elements in the set $\{in_<(f)\mid f\in I\}.$ So conceivably you could have some cancellation occurring so that $x^u\in in_<(I)$ but with no $f\in I$ with $in_<(f)=x^u$.

Comment: On it's own $x$ means nothing, but $x^u$ where $u\in\mathsbb{N}^n$ corresponds to a minomial. E.g. $x^{(1, 4, 0, 1)}=x_1^1x_2^4x_3^0x_4^1$

Comment: Ill ammend my question to add this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[As you already told](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1107980/121097), $\operatorname{in}_{<}(I)$ is the *ideal* generated by $\operatorname{in}_{<}(f)$ for *all* $f\in I$. This means that an element of $\operatorname{in}_{<}(I)$ is a linear combination of the form $g_1\operatorname{in}_{<}(f_1)+\cdots+g_r\operatorname{in}_{<}(f_r)$ with $f_i\in I$ and $g_i\in K[x_1,\dots,x_n]$. If a monomial $x^u\in\operatorname{in}_{<}(I)$ it writes  $x^u=g_1\operatorname{in}_{<}(f_1)+\cdots+g_r\operatorname{in}_{<}(f_r)$. Now look at the initial monomial of the right hand side: it is of the form $\operatorname{in}_{<}(g_i)\operatorname{in}_{<}(f_i)$, for some $i$, and since $\operatorname{in}_{<}(g_if_i)=\operatorname{in}_{<}(g_i)\operatorname{in}_{<}(f_i)$ and $g_if_i\in I$ we are done.

Comment: Don't worry if $\operatorname{in}_{<}(g_i)\operatorname{in}_{<}(f_i)=\operatorname{in}_{<}(g_j)\operatorname{in}_{<}(f_j)$ for $i\ne j$; they sum up or cancel.

Comment: I thought that $in_<(I)$ was a set of monomials only, is it instead an ideal itself?

Comment: @AndrewBrick It is an ideal, not a set.

Comment: so $in_<(f)$ are the generators of $in_<(I)$, I'm fairly new to working with ideals and the initial of ideals, do you have any resources which provide several examples to get comfortable with them, as I'm struggling to find some good examples

Comment: @AndrewBrick Google for Grobner bases, examples. Will find a lot of examples. (As I've told you in the previous answer, the initial ideal is almost impossible to determine unless you find a Grobner basis for that ideal.)

Comment: also, I thought that a monomial was a single term $x^u$ in a polynomial, but you've referred to $g_1in_<(f_1)+...+g_rin_<(f_r)$ as a monomial

Comment: @AndrewBrick When a monomial belongs to an ideal generated by some polynomials/monomials, then it is firstly a linear combination of the generators.

Comment: I see, thank you very much for your help

Comment: one last question about your proof, you said to look at the initial monomial on the right-hand side which is $in_<(g_i)in_<(f_i)$ for some $i$, and I understand why, but then aren't you showing that $in_<(x^u)=in_<(g_i)in_<(f_i)$, when instead it should be $x^u=in_<(g_i)in_<(f_i)$, or there a reason for $in_<(x^u)=x^u$

Comment: @AndrewBrick The initial monomial of a monomial is...?

Comment: The monomial itself, starting to realise it was a stupid question :)